# How to prioritize one executable in PATH over the other that has the same name and is in a different PATH file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path

I have two executables, which have the same name, for demonstration purposes let's say the name of the executable is "someexecutable.exe". Now I want to run the new version when I execute "someexecutable.exe" in the terminal yet it's running the older one. I have added the path of the new version to .profile and I have no idea in which PATH file the path for the old executable is set.

How does one set up PATH priority so that the when two executables with the same name are present, the terminal runs the one you want.

Answer (score 4):

The $PATH variable are searched in the order that is defined. So for example you have path1/someprogaram.exe followed by path2/someprogram.exe then path1 will be executed.

Now after you make the change by adding in your .profile make sure that you load the profile using

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or spawn a new shell.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not run your program with a full path?  Like

```
/foo/bar/yourapplication.exe
```

Then there will be no confusion.

You can also customize your `PATH` for a single command on Bash terminal

```
PATH=/foo/bar/:$PATH yourapplication.exe
```

This is useful if you run `yourapplication.exe` through a wrapper which doesn't know about the full path.