# Set $PATH's priority

Tags: debian, environment-variables, env

I have set the environment `$PATH` in the `.bashrc` file for **node** and **npm** to be in `/home/username/bin/`. When i check with `which node` for instance it points in the right place, that being `/home/username/bin/node` , **YET** when i try to `node -v` or `node` i get the `bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory` (the main location) so it does not get over it.

What can i do to set the priorities of them binaries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prioritize one executable in PATH over the other that has the same name and is in a different PATH file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966080/how-to-prioritize-one-executable-in-path-over-the-other-that-has-the-same-name-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First when i restarted `.bashrc` was that issue rising, the second time when i restarted `.bashrc` with `source ~/.bashrc` it was working. If there can be another option i will leave it open.

Thanks

Comment: please rephrase, its very confusing

Comment: only after two restartings of the `.bashrc` file using `source ~/.bashrc` it worked.

Comment: I bet you did not **check** the PATH variable.  If you just `echo $PATH` you get the PATH order in the **current shell session**.  It is just that, an order of directories that the shell walks left to right to find your binary.